# How to migrate project from one project server 2010 to another?

Tags: export, project-server, migrate

We have SP2010 enterprise with Project server 2010. After setup multiple projects in development farm, we would like to migrate the projects to UAT. I thought it should have some "import/export" feature but I fail to find any article talk about it. Could you please advice?

Comment: check this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sushrao/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another/

Comment: Don't have Project Server installed, but at least the 2007 version [had import-option available](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-a-project-to-Project-Server-0f8ddfb3-9d85-4d74-8c19-12f12e9f4b29). You could check if it's there in 2010 too, and which sort of file type it accepts. Could be the default file type of a Project Server project.

Comment: @moe but I fail to find any export/import button in MS Project 2010 professional. On project server (the website) I can export project tasks to Excel. But I cannot import it beside copy & paste the contents.

Comment: @TARUN the article is talking about migrate entire production server but I only want to move some projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Project Server that you can perform import/export operation for few sets of Project Plan.

As mentioned by Tarun you can migrate entire Project Database along with all Project Plan. If you want to migrate few set of Project, in that case, you will need to save Project Plan as .mpp on the local system using Project Professional and then Publish to UAT. In this Process, you need to make sure you have exact same custom fields and resources in both environments in order to avoid unexpected errors.